# Creating a 10*10 grid cell in matlab

Tags: matlab, grid

I am trying to get a empty 10*10 grid cell in order to fill it up with some outputs afterwards. The code I wrote is:

```
patch(1:100)=1:100;
mapmatrix= zeros(100,100);
for patchi=1:100,
 for cellxi=1:10,
  for cellyi=1:10,
   mapmatrix(mod(patchi-1,10)*10+cellxi,ceil(patchi/10)*10+cellyi)=patch(patchi);
,end,end,end;

imagesc(mapmatrix)
```

Does anyone know why I am getting a 10*11 grid cell instead of 10*10?

THX

Comment: `imagesc(mapmatrix==0)` - do you see what your problem is?

Comment: indeed @nkjt, mapmatrix(mod(patchi-1,10)*10+cellxi,ceil(patchi/10)*9+cellyi)=patch(patchi);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, that is because you use different index computing methods for cow and column indexes

```
mod(patchi-1,10)*10+cellxi
```

vs

```
ceil(patchi/10)*10+cellyi
```